# How to write OR condition between column of a table and its derived table in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table called Exams,

Table: Exams 
columns : id, user_id, title

Table : User
columns : id, name, age

User belongsTo Exam

Now, my I want to filter if Exam.user_id is NULL or Exam.User.name='Ramu' How can we do this in sequelize

Comment: please post some code , what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve that with Sequelize.col, but I think filtering after the query would result in cleaner code.

I haven't tested this, but something along those lines:

```
let exams = await Exam.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: User, as: 'user', required: false
  }]
});

let filteredExams = exams.filter(exam => (exam.user_id == null || (exam.user && exam.user.name == 'Ramu')));
```

Hope this helps!